# Sending an HTML email with an attachment

Tags: ruby, email, mime, email-attachments

I have a question about [net/smtp](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_sending_email.htm)

For html emails you have to set this in the header of the email `content-type: text/html` . However, if you want to send an attachment you have to change it to `content-type: multipart/mixed`. Which would make the html email...not html anymore.

So the question is.. how do I accomplish both? HTML and attachment?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Each attachment has its own MIME type

Each part of a multipart email has its own MIME type.  So, while the email's content-type is "multipart/mixed", each attachment has its own MIME type (text, HTML, etc).

Here is an example multipart email from [MIME and HTML in Email](http://abiglime.com/webmaster/articles/cgi/010698.htm) by Doug Steinwand:

```
To: whoever@someplace.com
Subject: MIME test
Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="theBoundaryString"

--theBoundaryString

Plain text message goes in this part. Notice that it
has a blank line before it starts, meaning that this
part has no additional headers.

--theBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Base: "http://somewebsite.com/"

<body><font size=4>This</font> is a 
<i>test</i>.
--theBoundaryString--
```

Here you can see that the text attachment has no explicit content type.  When an attachment has no explicit content type, it is US ASCII TEXT.  The HTML attachment has a content type of "text/html".  There could be other attachments, each with their own MIME type.

## Consider using the "mail" Gem

The [mail](http://rubygems.org/gems/mail) gem makes sending and parsing multi-part emails very easy.  It is stable, well maintained, and widely used.

This example from its [README](https://github.com/mikel/mail/) shows how to send a multi-part mail with a text part and an HTML part:

```
mail = Mail.deliver do
  to      'nicolas@test.lindsaar.net.au'
  from    'Mikel Lindsaar <mikel@test.lindsaar.net.au>'
  subject 'First multipart email sent with Mail'

  text_part do
    body 'This is plain text'
  end

  html_part do
    content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    body '<h1>This is HTML</h1>'
  end
end
```

Comment: When I add an attachment to this, like "add_file csv_file" only the attachment shows in the email client, no plain text or html. When I remove the html and text parts, and simply do body "body here" it shows the text and the attachment correctly. Ideas?

Comment: It actually shows correctly in gmail but not Apple Mail. I think the bug is documented here: https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/590. I'm taking a look.